# Should .delivery/ be on version control on my Chef Cookbook?

Tags: chef-infra

I noticed I have a `.delivery/` directory on my cookbook, but I'm not sure whether it's functionalities include sensitive data that's related to my Managed Chef Server (like private keys and more).

Should this directory be on version control?

Comment: It should be on version control if you use Chef Automate or delivery CLI to lint/build it. If not, you can just remove it.

Comment: I'm using Knife with Chef Manage (hosted chef server I think it's called). I'm new to Chef so I'm not sure whether Chef Automate is Chef Manage. I'm using knife commands to upload my cookbooks, and to bootstrap/update my nodes

Comment: Well I would say you don't need this directory then. But it's harmless to leave it there